# How to create data frame from named vectors

Tags: r

I have a vector such as this with data for multiple objects

```
vector <-  
(Intercept)            tt           jan           feb           mar           apr 
 16.798007e+02  4.840915e-05 -2.720942e+00 -3.342140e+00 -3.416526e+00 -1.626662e+00 
          may           jun           jul           aug           sep           oct 
 1.327538e+00  3.503917e+00  4.033163e+00  3.382681e+00  1.829954e+00  1.675477e-01 
          nov           dec           ar1           ma1   (Intercept)            tt 
-1.071309e+00 -2.067222e+00  1.990070e-01 -9.024502e-01  16.727682e+02  4.193033e-04 
          jan           feb           mar           apr           may           jun 
 5.081999e+00  3.542029e+00  1.142683e+00 -8.438593e-01 -2.265287e+00 -3.243971e+00 
          jul           aug           sep           oct           nov           dec 
-3.845346e+00 -3.828005e+00 -2.781550e+00 -2.665855e-01  2.627541e+00  4.680350e+00 
          ar1           ma1          sar1 
 2.925453e-01 -9.871875e-01 -3.389225e-02
```

As you can see each value is name, I would like to create a dataframe from this however there are some values missing, for example not every list has sma3, for this I would like the value to be 0. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a moderately tricky data wrangling excercise. It can be done in base R like this:

```r
vec_list <- split(vector, cumsum(names(vals) == "(Intercept)"))
all_names <- unique(names(vector))
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(vec_list, function(x) {
   miss <- all_names[!all_names %in% names(x)]
   if(length(miss) > 0) {
     extras <- rep(NA, length(miss))
     names(extras) <- miss
     x <- c(x, extras)
   }
   x[order(names(x))]
}))
```

which gives:

```r
df
#>    (Intercept)        apr         ar1          ar2       aug       dec       feb
#> 1     279.8007 -1.6266620  0.19900700           NA  3.382681 -2.067222 -3.342140
#> 2     272.7682 -0.8438593  0.29254530           NA -3.828005  4.680350  3.542029
#> 3     278.5023 -1.3296980  0.93756220 -0.089256400  3.550919 -2.377501 -3.315802
#> 4     278.6649 -1.6202500          NA           NA  3.341165 -1.887725 -3.264662
#> 5     278.3659 -1.5488060  0.29903390           NA  4.231421 -2.803281 -3.480161
#> 6     279.3122 -1.3809410  0.60769150 -0.001691358  3.210356 -2.214390 -3.217775
#> 7     276.7607 -1.3727650  1.18075200 -0.249806300  3.731505 -2.656473 -3.584222
#> 8     276.4724 -1.3801390  0.08658598  0.399049400  3.180014 -2.187161 -3.387232
#> 9     278.1629 -1.7310140  0.28360710 -0.026304670  3.096785 -1.753404 -3.301081
#> 10    277.9096 -2.1937890  1.37309800 -0.390203600  4.161024 -2.240281 -4.443509
#> 11    277.0103 -1.2304630 -0.61192070  0.162234600  3.448405 -2.166346 -3.580056
#> 12    276.9348 -1.4335210  0.44845850           NA  3.587970 -2.420724 -3.478253
#> 13    277.0602 -1.9601050  0.95891980 -0.158067800  3.862413 -2.171699 -3.620072
#>    intercept       jan       jul       jun        ma1         ma2         ma3       mar
#> 1         NA -2.720942  4.033163  3.503917 -0.9024502          NA          NA -3.416526
#> 2         NA  5.081999 -3.845346 -3.243971 -0.9871875          NA          NA  1.142683
#> 3         NA -2.898817  4.038097  3.378529 -1.6670330  0.67040200          NA -3.112006
#> 4         NA -2.724990  3.707669  2.882694 -0.6042674 -0.09197413 -0.08133493 -3.229687
#> 5         NA -3.276840  4.649857  3.447666 -0.9154890          NA          NA -3.144361
#> 6         NA -2.978016  3.807138  3.210342 -1.2678360  0.28332570          NA -2.929295
#> 7  -3.056346 -3.370165  4.607691  3.948105 -0.8591602          NA          NA -3.134291
#> 8         NA -2.858129  4.113266  3.699703 -0.6787307 -0.52316940  0.21762660 -3.184402
#> 9         NA -2.647391  3.625498  2.961957 -0.9103049          NA          NA -3.286306
#> 10 -1.889277 -3.714646  4.417645  3.467205 -0.9279671          NA          NA -4.173118
#> 11        NA -3.011898  4.198331  3.540399 -0.1316260 -0.77494290          NA -3.317243
#> 12        NA -3.244379  3.993380  3.354898 -1.1101730  0.15407080          NA -3.158491
#> 13        NA -3.106563  4.134632  2.958062 -1.5902690  0.60139470          NA -3.484582
#>           may        nov         oct        sar1        sar2       sep        sma1
#> 1   1.3275380 -1.0713090  0.16754770          NA          NA  1.829954          NA
#> 2  -2.2652870  2.6275410 -0.26658550 -0.03389225          NA -2.781550          NA
#> 3   1.4608710 -1.5712550  0.09459663  0.34549720 -0.04374952  2.082068 -0.32383530
#> 4   1.0468810 -0.8545025  0.51976090          NA          NA  2.083648          NA
#> 5   0.9464126 -1.6588850  0.19920530          NA          NA  2.437772          NA
#> 6   1.2649990 -0.9592783  0.36743300          NA          NA  1.819426          NA
#> 7   1.4688440 -1.5588700  0.01279821          NA          NA  1.907842 -0.04720893
#> 8   1.6186780 -1.2567640  0.03604443 -0.50325120 -0.62357390  1.606121  0.52404810
#> 9   1.0925790 -0.6581407  0.65308330 -0.09950496          NA  1.947435  0.01589627
#> 10  1.0581740 -0.4414327  1.24294400          NA          NA  2.859782          NA
#> 11  1.6393420 -1.2209990  0.07090338          NA          NA  1.629625          NA
#> 12  1.3407050 -1.1763280  0.49709980          NA          NA  2.137644          NA
#> 13  0.5692828 -0.7286658  1.00451300          NA          NA  2.542785          NA
#>         sma2            tt
#> 1         NA  3.830915e-05
#> 2         NA  1.193033e-04
#> 3         NA  4.842183e-05
#> 4         NA -1.064002e-04
#> 5         NA  9.999572e-05
#> 6         NA  6.719809e-05
#> 7         NA  1.504109e-05
#> 8  0.5869298 -1.024007e-05
#> 9         NA  2.003572e-06
#> 10        NA  3.350972e-05
#> 11        NA  2.130839e-04
#> 12        NA  1.587899e-04
#> 13        NA -3.860078e-05
```

It was almost as difficult to get the data you posted into a reproducible example:

**Data**

```r
vector <- c(`(Intercept)` = 279.8007, tt = 3.830915e-05, jan = -2.720942, 
feb = -3.34214, mar = -3.416526, apr = -1.626662, may = 1.327538, 
jun = 3.503917, jul = 4.033163, aug = 3.382681, sep = 1.829954, 
oct = 0.1675477, nov = -1.071309, dec = -2.067222, ar1 = 0.199007, 
ma1 = -0.9024502, `(Intercept)` = 272.7682, tt = 0.0001193033, 
jan = 5.081999, feb = 3.542029, mar = 1.142683, apr = -0.8438593, 
may = -2.265287, jun = -3.243971, jul = -3.845346, aug = -3.828005, 
sep = -2.78155, oct = -0.2665855, nov = 2.627541, dec = 4.68035, 
ar1 = 0.2925453, ma1 = -0.9871875, sar1 = -0.03389225, `(Intercept)` = 278.5023, 
tt = 4.842183e-05, jan = -2.898817, feb = -3.315802, mar = -3.112006, 
apr = -1.329698, may = 1.460871, jun = 3.378529, jul = 4.038097, 
aug = 3.550919, sep = 2.082068, oct = 0.09459663, nov = -1.571255, 
dec = -2.377501, ar1 = 0.9375622, ar2 = -0.0892564, ma1 = -1.667033, 
ma2 = 0.670402, sar1 = 0.3454972, sar2 = -0.04374952, sma1 = -0.3238353, 
`(Intercept)` = 278.6649, tt = -0.0001064002, jan = -2.72499, 
feb = -3.264662, mar = -3.229687, apr = -1.62025, may = 1.046881, 
jun = 2.882694, jul = 3.707669, aug = 3.341165, sep = 2.083648, 
oct = 0.5197609, nov = -0.8545025, dec = -1.887725, ma1 = -0.6042674, 
ma2 = -0.09197413, ma3 = -0.08133493, `(Intercept)` = 278.3659, 
tt = 9.999572e-05, jan = -3.27684, feb = -3.480161, mar = -3.144361, 
apr = -1.548806, may = 0.9464126, jun = 3.447666, jul = 4.649857, 
aug = 4.231421, sep = 2.437772, oct = 0.1992053, nov = -1.658885, 
dec = -2.803281, ar1 = 0.2990339, ma1 = -0.915489, `(Intercept)` = 279.3122, 
tt = 6.719809e-05, jan = -2.978016, feb = -3.217775, mar = -2.929295, 
apr = -1.380941, may = 1.264999, jun = 3.210342, jul = 3.807138, 
aug = 3.210356, sep = 1.819426, oct = 0.367433, nov = -0.9592783, 
dec = -2.21439, ar1 = 0.6076915, ar2 = -0.001691358, ma1 = -1.267836, 
ma2 = 0.2833257, `(Intercept)` = 276.7607, tt = 1.504109e-05, 
jan = -3.370165, feb = -3.584222, mar = -3.134291, apr = -1.372765, 
may = 1.468844, jun = 3.948105, jul = 4.607691, aug = 3.731505, 
sep = 1.907842, oct = 0.01279821, nov = -1.55887, dec = -2.656473, 
ar1 = 1.180752, ar2 = -0.2498063, ma1 = -0.8591602, sma1 = -0.04720893, 
intercept = -3.056346, `(Intercept)` = 276.4724, tt = -1.024007e-05, 
jan = -2.858129, feb = -3.387232, mar = -3.184402, apr = -1.380139, 
may = 1.618678, jun = 3.699703, jul = 4.113266, aug = 3.180014, 
sep = 1.606121, oct = 0.03604443, nov = -1.256764, dec = -2.187161, 
ar1 = 0.08658598, ar2 = 0.3990494, ma1 = -0.6787307, ma2 = -0.5231694, 
ma3 = 0.2176266, sar1 = -0.5032512, sar2 = -0.6235739, sma1 = 0.5240481, 
sma2 = 0.5869298, `(Intercept)` = 278.1629, tt = 2.003572e-06, 
jan = -2.647391, feb = -3.301081, mar = -3.286306, apr = -1.731014, 
may = 1.092579, jun = 2.961957, jul = 3.625498, aug = 3.096785, 
sep = 1.947435, oct = 0.6530833, nov = -0.6581407, dec = -1.753404, 
ar1 = 0.2836071, ar2 = -0.02630467, ma1 = -0.9103049, sar1 = -0.09950496, 
sma1 = 0.01589627, `(Intercept)` = 277.9096, tt = 3.350972e-05, 
jan = -3.714646, feb = -4.443509, mar = -4.173118, apr = -2.193789, 
may = 1.058174, jun = 3.467205, jul = 4.417645, aug = 4.161024, 
sep = 2.859782, oct = 1.242944, nov = -0.4414327, dec = -2.240281, 
ar1 = 1.373098, ar2 = -0.3902036, ma1 = -0.9279671, intercept = -1.889277, 
`(Intercept)` = 277.0103, tt = 0.0002130839, jan = -3.011898, 
feb = -3.580056, mar = -3.317243, apr = -1.230463, may = 1.639342, 
jun = 3.540399, jul = 4.198331, aug = 3.448405, sep = 1.629625, 
oct = 0.07090338, nov = -1.220999, dec = -2.166346, ar1 = -0.6119207, 
ar2 = 0.1622346, ma1 = -0.131626, ma2 = -0.7749429, `(Intercept)` = 276.9348, 
tt = 0.0001587899, jan = -3.244379, feb = -3.478253, mar = -3.158491, 
apr = -1.433521, may = 1.340705, jun = 3.354898, jul = 3.99338, 
aug = 3.58797, sep = 2.137644, oct = 0.4970998, nov = -1.176328, 
dec = -2.420724, ar1 = 0.4484585, ma1 = -1.110173, ma2 = 0.1540708, 
`(Intercept)` = 277.0602, tt = -3.860078e-05, jan = -3.106563, 
feb = -3.620072, mar = -3.484582, apr = -1.960105, may = 0.5692828, 
jun = 2.958062, jul = 4.134632, aug = 3.862413, sep = 2.542785, 
oct = 1.004513, nov = -0.7286658, dec = -2.171699, ar1 = 0.9589198, 
ar2 = -0.1580678, ma1 = -1.590269, ma2 = 0.6013947)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  lapply(
    split(
      vector,
      findInterval(seq_along(vector), which(names(vector) == "(Intercept)"))
    ),
    function(x) x[match(names(x), unique(names(vector)))]
  )
)
```